# Error with variadic function in Clojure

Tags: clojure, variadic-functions

I am trying to write a custom `max` function in Clojure, which should support one or more arguments. However, I am running into an error that I cannot figure out. Here is the below function:

```
(defn my-max [arg & rest]                                                            
  (loop [m arg c rest]                                                               
    (cond (empty? c) m                                                               
          (> m (first c)) (recur m (rest c))                                         
          :else (recur (first c) (rest c)))))
```

And I encounter the following error when attempting to evaluate the function:

```
user> (my-max 2 3 1 4 5)                                                                                                                                                    
ClassCastException clojure.lang.ArraySeq cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn  user/my-max (NO_SOURCE_FILE:5)
```

I thought this would work because I was under the assumption that `rest` was just a sequence. I was able to get this function to work without a variadic signature, where the argument is simply a sequence:

```
(defn my-max [coll]                                                                                                                                                            
  (loop [m (first coll) c (rest coll)]                                                                                                                                         
    (cond (empty? c) m                                                                                                                                                         
          (> m (first c)) (recur m (rest c))                                                                                                                                   
          :else (recur (first c) (rest c)))))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem appears to be a name collision. You have used the name `rest` for the tail sequence of your calling arguments. Then you subsequently try to use the function `rest`, but that sequence is seen instead.

Comment: Yes, that was it. I am not sure why I didn't see that earlier -- sometimes I need a sanity check.

Comment: This is where perhaps one day we might hope for some compiler warnings.

Comment: @A. Webb - agree, this is exactly why we need some more static type checking in Clojure. Would pick up this kind of thing immediately.

Comment: For this particular case, checking wouldn't need types. Lists do not implement `IFn` so attempting to invoke a 'rest' argument would be undoubtedly a programming mistake.